# I am working on vectors in C++, however this simple code is throwing error somewhere

Tags: c++11, vector

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int firstMissingPositive(vector<int> A) {
    sort(A.begin() , A.end());
    int i,start=-1,j;
    for(i=0; i<A.size(); i++)//to find the least positive number
    {
        if(A.at(i)>=0)
        {
            start=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(start==-1)
    return 1; //when the vector has no positive number
    else
    {
        for(j=start; j<=A.at(A.size()); j++)//to find the least positive missing number
        {
              if ( find(A.begin(), A.end(), i)!=A.end() )
              continue;
              else
              return i;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> b;
    int myarray [] = { 501,504,503 };
    b.insert (b.begin(), myarray, myarray+3);
    firstMissingPositive(b);
}
```

> The error shown is: **terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'std::out_of_range' what<>: vector::_M_range_check**

I have been dealing with this since long but can not detect the err in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you are stuck at this statement:

```
for(j=start; j<=A.at(A.size()); j++)  //to find the least positive missing number
```

It should be:

```
for(j=start; j<=A.at(A.size()-1); j++)
```

because you are trying to access `A.size()`th element which is throwing `out_of_range` error.